# Writing to a new excel sheet in the same file without deleting previous data (nodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

Morning everyone. I am having a small issue when it comes to writing to an excel file with code. The data is writing to the excel correctly but I want to start a new sheet in that same excel file. How do I do that with code?

Summary
Write new data to excel on a new sheet every time without overwriting anything.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any libraries? Have you looked at this?: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/msexcel-builder

Comment: Nope not using any libraries. Will check that one out and get back to you